# How to call Sweet Alert 2 confirmation on PHP echo link?

Tags: php, sweetalert2

I need help, please.
As part of the table, I have echo a link to a controller for the next phase, but I want a Sweet Alert 2 confirmation before the controller is executed. I am new to PHP so I always get errors on the code when I insert the onclick command and the controller link on Sweet alert  code.
The link

```
echo "<td><a href = '".base_url()."index.php/start_phase2/".$p->id_project."'>Finish Phase 1</a></td>";
```

Sweet alert code

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form #btn-ok').click(function(e) {
    let $form = $(this).closest('form');

    const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
        customClass: {
            confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
        },
        buttonsStyling: false,
    })

    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
        title: 'Are you  sure?',
        text: "Check plz",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'OK',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                    'Finished',
                    'Success',
                    'success',
                );                     
            $form.submit();
        } else if (
            result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
        ) {
            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                'Canceled',
                'Do corrections and then retry :)',
                'error'
            );
        }
    });

});
```

close script

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you want to fire swalWithBootstrapButtons for a confirmation before sending to the controller ? Then what error did you get?

Comment: It's not working yet.

Answer (score 1):

After clicking the a tab, a window will pop up to confirm?

Comment: Yes, i just want a confirmation modals

Comment: Hi and welcome! If the question is unclear ask the author to edit their post. Or to a certain limit uses comments. That's not an answer.

Comment: Write click event，then Sweet Alert。preConfirm A connection jump？